# Silex: put and post handled differently

Tags: php, rest, symfony, silex

I'm using Silex to create a REST API. I created an update method which takes a resource id and request data and updates the matching resource.

At first I tested it using the route:

```
$api->post('/websites/{id}', "websites.controller:update");
```

This worked fine and updated the resource as expected.

I then changed the route to:

```
$api->put('/websites/{id}', "websites.controller:update");
```

The update method of the controller hasn't been changed at all, but the request is now failing. The request data seems to be empty, doing:

```
$request->request->get('key');
```

isn't returning anything although it was when using POST.

Any ideas why the implementation may differ?

Answer (score 0):

No idea why the implementations would be different. If you know the key you want, you can always do `$request->get('KeyName')` for any method.

Comment: It's wrong. The Silex stores GET in `$request->query`

Comment: No, if you want to get PUT, you need to use `$request->get('key')`, because `$request->query->get('key')` is only for GET method. Look at [Request](http://api.symfony.com/2.5/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/Request.html#method___construct) docs

Comment: A caveat - in order for Silex/Symfony to serialize the request data with the `$request->get()` method, you need to ensure your calls are setting the `Content-Type` header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.